# Getting thin to read configured user environment

Tags: ruby, rack, thin

I'm starting thin with a parameter set like the following under ubuntu

```
chdir: /var/www/myuser/current
rackup: /var/www/myuser/current/config.ru
environment: production
address: 0.0.0.0
port: 3000
timeout: 30
log: log/thin.log
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
max_conns: 1024
max_persistent_conns: 512
require: []
wait: 30
servers: 3
daemonize: true
user: myuser
group: myuser
```

And I want to define a set of environment variables for "myuser" so they can be accessible in the rack application I'm deploying in Thin with `ENV['MY_VAR']`.

Can I do some configuration without adding the variables one by one to the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/usage/

You can create a YAML file in your app directory and start up the server like:

```
thin -C ./config.yml
```

Either that, or I didn't really understand the question!

Comment: I'm talking about system environment variables such as $PATH

Comment: Is using a session/key-value store feasible? You can store the variables in them and then use it everywhere else.

Comment: Yes. Indeed that's what I finally made but I just needed some already defined environment and wanted to avoid the duplication.