# Environment variables with Rackup, Thin, and Oracle

Tags: oracle, sinatra, thin, oci8, rackup

I've written a server using Sinatra that accesses an Oracle database using ActiveRecord (though this is not a Rails app). I wrote it in Sinatra's "classic" style and previously started the server like this:

```
bundle exec ruby bin/server.rb
```

I also used `require 'thin'` and Thin was magically used as the HTTP server. However, I needed to change Thin's default timeout, so I transitioned to a rackup `config.ru` file. I now start the server like this:

```
bundle exec thin -C config/thin.yml -R config/config.ru start
```

However, since doing this I can't connect to the Oracle database with the server. I'm using a service name and the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable is set correctly and I can connect with `sqlplus` or even the same server if not launched using Thin. Launching with Thin, when I try to start the connection I get `OCIError - ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`.

**What is the right way to set environment variables for servers launched with Thin?** The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294815/getting-thin-to-read-configured-user-environment) doesn't work because I can't give ruby-oci8 the information, it automatically reads them from the environment.

Comment: So, you have somewhere in your code `ENV["TNS_ADMIN"]` and for some reason this env variable isn't accessible or quite right when using Thin, so the connection fails? The command looks slighty wrong, shouldn't it be `bundle exec thin start -C config/thin.yml -R config/config.ru`?  On a side note, I heartily recommend using `bundle install --binstubs` and then you can use `bin/thin` or (whichever command) instead.

Comment: `ENV["TNS_ADMIN"]` is not accessed by my code but by the Oracle library (ruby-oci8), unfortunately. It looks correct within the library code (`puts ENV["TNS_ADMIN"]` is what I expect), but doesn't appear to be used correctly in the C part of the library.

Comment: What's in the config.ru? Have you tried `env TNS_ADMIN='some value' bundle exec thin start -C config/thin.yml -R config/config.ru`?

Comment: config.ru is two lines: `require 'server.rb'`, `run Sinatra::Application`. Tried env but I got the same Oracle error.

Comment: Could it be that the `server.rb` file isn't being required properly? Try `require_relative "../bin/server.rb"`. If you use my earlier advice about bundler binstubs then you may want to move it out of bin to stop being clobbered! Sorry if this advice seems a bit lame, but I can't see anything _obviously_ wrong with what you've done. Which I'm sure is of no comfort :/

Comment: Well, I switched from Thin to Unicorn and things just worked.